# Between tls_rsa_with_aes_256_cbc_sha and tls_rsa_with_aes_128_cbc_sha256 which one is more secure?

Tags: ssl, encryption, openssl

Which of the following cipher suites is more secure?

- tls_rsa_with_aes_256_cbc_sha
- tls_rsa_with_aes_128_cbc_sha256

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AES-256 has nearly twice the security level as AES-128, given all other things being equal. SHA-256 has nearly twice the security level as SHA-1 (which is 160-bits). SHA-256 provides 128 bits of security. SHA-1 should provide 80-bits of security, but its practical security is around 65-bits.

Security levels do not equate to "twice as strong" (thanks Iridium). AES-256 has a security level of 256-bits, while AES-128 has a security level of about 128-bits. That means AES-256 needs about (2<sup>256</sup>)/2 operations to brute force, while AES-128 needs about (2<sup>128</sup>)/2 operations to brute force.

The use of the hashes in TLS is different than a long term signature, like the signature on a document or on a certificate. General signatures on documents and certificates need to survive for years or decades. In TLS, the signature over a record only needs to withstand as long as it takes for a packet to timeout on the network, which is a matter of minutes.

In practice for TLS, there's no effective difference between them. They are both hard, and your attacker will circumvent the encryption and try to attack you in other ways. He or she will find a weaker point in the system.

For example, the attacker might try to obtain the key used for key *transport* (that's the RSA in `tls_rsa_*`) by planting malware on the server through an injection. Then the attacker can simply calculate the 6 keys used in a TLS connection from the premaster secret that was transported and recovered under the compromised key.

As another example, the US government demanded [Lavabit's private key](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2014/may/20/why-did-lavabit-shut-down-snowden-email) so they could do the same. The US government could skirt the "plant malware" step through the legal system.

Comment: Where does your statement regarding AES-256 being "nearly twice as strong as AES-128" come from? Assuming no faster-than-brute-force attacks, AES-256 would be a *power of 2* stronger than AES-128. (A key only 1 bit longer would be twice as strong).

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right Iridium. I was thinking security levels. Let me get that corrected.